# how to evaluate a given path within a bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, unix, path

Is there a bash command that takes as input a file path and returns an absolute file path?
More specifically I would like a command that takes as input a path such as:

```
/tmp/yaneeve/kit/linux/../../output/kit/SOURCES//usr//apps/myapp/lib
```

and returns the path:

```
/tmp/yaneeve/output/kit/SOURCES/usr/apps/myapp/lib
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try (Linux)

```
readlink -f
```

Comment: Hi all,

Notice that I've found a bug (?) in readlink. When the path does not really exist it appends only the first part to its output.

For example:

say the input is /tmp/yaneeve/apps/newapp/guide/eng

and say that the deepest part of this path that exists is /tmp/yaneeve/apps

the output would be /tmp/yaneeve/apps/newapp

Any comments on this finding?

Comment: It doesn't output anything here, for nonexisting pathes (I used exactly your example).

Comment: Please note that readlink -f is a physical path evaluation. All symbolic links in the path are resolved from left to right. This often give surprising results because it isn't always clear what folder is a symbolic link (and I guess you don't want to know). If you want to evaluate your logical path you can use the realpath -L or the solution with $(cd "$path"; pwd). Both do the logical evaluation and don't resolve symbolic links

Answer (score 17):

If the path exists, there is a portable way which is (even on linux) far more reliable:

```
canonicalPath=$(cd "$path"; pwd)
```

Comment: Good catch. Is there any need to use the external pwd program? The internal one follows the logical path, which diesn't need to match the "physical" one.

Comment: mkdir a "dir1", create a link "dir2" to it, cd dir2, compare pwd and command pwd.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `realpath` if the path exists:

```bash
realpath /tmp/yaneeve/kit/linux/../../output/kit/SOURCES/usr/apps/myapp/lib
```

gives:

```
/tmp/yaneeve/output/kit/SOURCES/usr/apps/myapp/lib
```

From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/realpath):

> realpath - return the canonicalised absolute pathname

Comment: The OP asked about the absolute path and didn't mention if this is an logical or physical path evaluation. Most users expect the logical evaluation, so in that case you need to add -L option.